# c# mvc - authorize ajax function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a code that calls the "Delete" action from my FriendApi but I'd like to authorize it. I authorized the Delete action in the Api, users that are not admins can still "delete" data but when I refresh the page the data's still there. How can I authorize this and make sure that, if someone's not admin and he clicks "Delete", he gets asked to log in with an account that has privileges to do this action. Here's my Api and my Index page, where the Api gets called.

```
// DELETE: api/FriendApi/5
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(FriendModel))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteFriendModel(int id)
        {
            FriendModel friendModel = db.friends.Find(id);
            if (friendModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.friends.Remove(friendModel);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(friendModel);
        }
```

Here's my index. So my main goal is to make it visible for the "Manager" role but only an "Admin" role can delete stuff.

```
@model List<MVCLab5._1.Models.FriendModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Friend ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            //int i = 0;

            foreach (var obj in Model)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@obj.FriendId</td>
                    <td>@obj.Name</td>
                    <td>@obj.Place</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Manager"))
                        {

                        <button data-friend-id="@obj.Id" class="btn btn-default js-delete">Delete</button>
                        }

                        @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteFriend", new { id = obj.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })*@
                @if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Manager"))
                {
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditFriend", new { id = obj.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
                }
                    </td>


                </tr>
                //i++;

            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
            $("#myTable .js-delete").on("click", function () {
                var button = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/FriendApi/" + button.attr("data-friend-id"),
                    method: "DELETE",
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result)
                        table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Could you set a break point inside `DeleteFriendModel` action method and ensure that the break point get hit?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the user currently logged in. I do not know which authentication approach you are using.

Taking an example, you are using your custom cookies authentication. In this case you receive a unique token in each request (wrapped in as a cookie entry), and using this token you can know which user is currently logged in, i.e., you can look in the database to check which permissions does he have, and accordingly decide to authorize him or not.

Comment: Yeah I know that. My question is how to Authorize an Ajax function. "Delete" button should be visible to Manager and Admin but only an Admin can delete on it. If a Manager clicks on it, it should redirect him to a login page

Comment: @AnthinoRusso Is your problem on client or server side? which part of implementation idea is not clear to you?